# Finding the position of the first character of a substring in a larger string

Tags: c, string, for-loop, substring

So my problem is that I need to find the numerical position of a substring in a larger string using for loops. I cannot use a string function such as strstr, and I have tried most iterations of nested for loops.

Basically I need a loop that goes through a string looking for a certain substring, and if it matches with the first characters, checks to see that the rest of the characters match as well.

If everything matches, it will return the position of the first character of the substring, and if nothing is found, then it will return -1.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us an example of the substring and larger string? and what position you expect returned?

Comment: What do you mean when you say _"I cannot use a string function such as strstr"_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly describe, this can be done with 2 nested loops:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  // for size_t

int indexof(const char *str, const char *substr) {
    for (size_t i = 0;; i++) {
        /* for every position in the string */
        for (size_t j = 0;; j++) {
            /* check of all characters fro substr match at this offset */
            if (substr[j] == '\0') {
                /* if we reach the end of substr, we have a match at offset i */
                return i;
            }
            if (str[i + j] != substr[j]) {
                /* if there is a mismatch, stop checking and skip to the next offset */
                break;
            }
        }
        if (str[i] == '\0') {
            /* no match found: return -1 */
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The function is specified as returning an `int` because it returns `-1` for no match. Yet the offset of the match might not fit in the range of `int`.  Returning a signed type such as `ssize_t` defined in POSIX would not completely fix this problem on 32-bit systems if more than 2GB of data can be accessed.
- The function could be make a little faster by testing the first character of substring explicitly.
- For long strings and substrings, more advanced algorithms such as [Boyer Moore's](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node14.html) and [Knuth Morris Pratt's](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node8.html) can run substantially faster.

Comment: For what it's worth, using a specific string search algorithm such as KMP can help this task be more efficient.

Comment: I just tested the code, but forgot to mention that it should work for strings with spaces as well. Is it possible to modify this to include spaces? So if I were searching "The cat is cool" for the substring "cat" it would return the integer 4 as it includes spaces.

Comment: @Monty: what do you mean by *including spaces*? Searching for `"cat"` in `"The cat is cool"` will find it at offset 4 already.